# Making a random testbank in API.ai

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

Would someone please explain or point me to a tutorial to develop a random question testbank chatbot in API.ai.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend starting with https://triviatemplate.com/ which creates an entire Google Assistant app for you, you just provide the questions.  In the background Trivia Templates creates an API.AI agent in the background for you in the background and deploys it to the Google Assistant.

After you've created your Trivia template assistant app, you can login to API.AI with the same account and see the agent that was created for you, tweak the responses or edit the functionality and deploy to other platforms (Facebook Messenger, Slack, Alexa, etc.)